# How to achieve Thread Safety in Java between Multiple JVM or containers if they access shared memory?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

We Know that Synchronized Keyword would work when there is only one JVM but if there more than 1 JVM , meaning there are more than 1 instance of JVM , So in that case how can we achieve thread safety ?

Given , each container creates its own separate instance . Suppose I have 3 separate jvm instance and these instances doing some transaction credit or debit on same account , then how can i make these transactions serialised or atomic or mutually exclusive. Can anyone tell the best approach ?

Comment: it is quite complex and broad so maybe you could narrow the scope of your question by providing a concrete use case

Comment: This is a hard problem. Your options depend on the circumstances.

Comment: Same question applies to multiple computers. As said above, too complex and broad; narrow the scope.

Comment: Generally you're looking for "distributed locking"; if it's all within a single OS, there are likely some built-in constructs you can use; if it's across more than one OS or machine, you probably need a service which you can delegate locking to.

Comment: The multiple instance run in the same machine? or diferente machine?

Comment: How do you create the shared memory? The only standard API way to create shared memory in Java is using a memory mapped file. Then, locking the file or regions of it, is the canonical solution.

Comment: For the same box: use system mutexes over JNI or CAS-based locking on a memory address over sun.misc.Unsafe. For a system distributed across the network use distributed locks like ones provided by Zookeeper, for instance

Answer (score 0):

Since the Synchronized keyword and the Lock provided by JVM only works for standalone application, you can not use those technologies to keep thread safe in cluster.

The general way to do that, or the simplest way is by the transaction provided by the Relational Database.

Or you can use other techs to implement the distributed lock, as far as I know you can use Zookeeper, Redis to achieve that.